# Modal text is repeting in other modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

I am doing a project where I have a table with several rows and in one of the columns of the table I have buttons that when clicked show a modal.

This modal has a `input` and a `div` where the `input` written will appear.

The problem is what I write in a single modal appears in the other modals.

Is there a way to make them "independent"? Below is the code I have written.

When you run the snippet below, that's something like that that appears in the
modal. And the text that you write in the input and goes to the div, is what is repeating in all the modals.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // send message to modal if message is empty do not send anything or if it is only spaces
  $("#sendMessage").click(function() {
    if ($.trim($("#inputToSend").val()) == "") {
      //do not send anything
    } else {
      $(".textModal").append(
        '<p class="msg">' + $("#inputToSend").val() + "</p>"
      );
      $("#inputToSend")
        .val("")
        .focus();
    }
  });

  // when modal button is closed text is erased
  $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    $(".modal-body").html("");
    $(".modal-title").html("");
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-title {
    background: #66a3ff;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal-body {
    padding: 30px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

#messageInput {
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

#sendMessage {
    margin: 15px 0px; 
}

#inputToSend {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 730px;
}

#messageSaved {
    margin: 0px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: inset;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align:justify; 
}

.msg {
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="btn-id" class="btn btn-sm btn-focus" style="padding: 8px;" data-id="{{ $complaint->_id }}" data-msg="{{ $complaint->ns1aussage }}" data-complain="{{ $complaint->ns1teileidentnr }}" data-backdrop="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>


<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h6 class="modal-title" id="title"></h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                   </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div id="messageInput">
        <div id="messageSaved" class="textModal"></div>
        <input id="inputToSend" type="text" class="text form-control" placeholder="Insert Message...">
        <button id="sendMessage" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do all of your modal boxes have the `id` of `basicModal`?

Comment: @MattHamer5 Yes they use all the same modal

Comment: @MattHamer5 I was searching and I have seen like id's being generated random, as id=" 'basicModal_" + "random' ", something like this but I don't know if this would be something "appliable" to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are referring to the `.modal-body` with `$(".modal-body")`, and there are probably more modals with the same `class` name

You should be more specific if you want to refer to a specific modal.

You can replace `$(".modal-body")` with `$("#basicModal .modal-body")` to select only the `.modal-body` that is under the parent `#basicModal`

Comment: The thing is, the modal above is used to all the buttons when they're clicked

Comment: Oh and the message that is repeated is the message given by input in $("#sendMessage").click(function() { ...

Comment: @ack31 I couldn't understand the problem :(, have you tried to refer to the modal using it's `ID` ?